# SONY Red Led notification not working

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notification-led, sony-xperia-z5

I have a SONY XPERIA Z5 Premium . The problem is the tiny LED notification light doesn't show red light. i have tried various led light management applications from the play store but still ain't working. What may be causing this? Running Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the LED through the service menu?

To enter the service menu go to the dialer and paste in the following code

```
*#*#7378423#*#*
```

Select

> Service tests

and then

> LED/Illumination

The LED should start to blink in green then blue then red. If your led is not blinking red I would suggest your LED is broken.

Comment: Hey, i have tried those tests....only the green and blue colors are functional. I meant the red color ain't working when it's set

Comment: Then I believe the LED is broken. Can you return it to the store for a refund?

Comment: Unfortunately , the device is a second hand and is not under any Warranty. I thot the led module works as one unit.

Comment: Well I'm not sure but according to wikipedia "tri-color LEDs contain three different LED emitters in one case. Each emitter is connected to a separate lead so they can be controlled independently."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode